# Custom NavigationItem's TouchUpInside Event is outside boundaries

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationbar, touch-event

I'm using a custom UIBarButtonItem to replace the leftBarButtonItem, however when I press outside of the button, within around 20 pixels of the button, it detects it as the button being pressed.

Here's my code:

```
- (void)changeNavbarButtons
{
    UIButton *backButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44)];
    [backButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbarBack.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(popViewController) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIBarButtonItem *backItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];

    UIBarButtonItem *negativeSpacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                       initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace
                                       target:nil action:nil];
    negativeSpacer.width = -5;

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [NSArray
                                              arrayWithObjects:negativeSpacer, backItem, nil];    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
}
```

The negativeSpacer is to move the button 5 pixels to the left.

What would be causing this?

Comment: This is not a bug it is the default behaviour of this button.

Comment: Oh, I never noticed that. Thanks Shannoga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the default behaviour of `UINavigationBarButton` item.
It's about ease of use. The navigation bar at the top tends to mean people tap lower than you may expect. Always leave that gap there, or have a sufficiently large hit area that the user stabbing their finger towards the middle of your "below the nav bar" item will avoid the dead area.